# A Problem With Coordinate Systems

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry

Consider a coordinate system $\cal{C}$ such that the concentric half circles around two fixed points $P_1,P_2$ in the plane above line $P_1P_2$ create the grid. So any point in the upper half plane in this coordinate system looks like $(r,s)$ where $r$ and $s$ are the radius of circle around $P_1,P_2$ respectively.

Consider an arbitrary point in $\cal{C}$ be $(r_1,s_1)$. Consider this point as the origin of upper half of a Cartesian coordinate with $x$-axis parallel to the line $P_1P_2$. Let $(a,b)$ be any point in this Cartesian coordinate system and $(r_2,s_2)$ be the corresponding point in $\cal{C}$. Determine $r_2-r_1$ and $s_2-s_1$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Given a typical point that is on the circle with radius $r$ around $P_1$ and on the circle with radius $s$ around $P_2,$ there is a second point where these same two circles intersect. That is, the coordinates $(r,s)$ do not generally uniquely identify points. If you restrict the coordinates to just the part of the plane on or above the line $P_1P_2,$ however, the coordinates are unique.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for pointing it. I have corrected it.